# Certificate distributing. *pfx\*cer

Tags: .net, silverlight, certificate

So I've got some silverlight application that uses some certificate.

Can you give an advice to me, what is the best way to distribute this certificate automatically to developers PCs?

I don't want to ask each developer to setting in up on his system.

So... maybe some sfx... maybe some other variant..

Any propositions?

Comment: Where are the certificates generated? What operating system?

Comment: In a domain together? But where are the certificates generated? The easiest thing would be to use Microsoft active directory certificate services.

Comment: This certificate generated with makecert utility on Windows enviroment

Comment: No way to use AD thingie? It's meant for exactly this task, distributing certs across your network....